# Why List indexWhere return -1 when no element found?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Why return -1 rather than `null` or other number?

Return `null` would be more user-friendly as far as I can see.

What's the internal design idea?

Comment: I believe it mimics JavaScript, since Dart was originally designed to be a better JavaScript.

Comment: maybe it because of the naming of the function  ``indexWhere`` , so it should be a index value ,if return null when no found the should name ``indexOrNullWhere`` something like that